# how can i interface with windows application from AIR application?

Tags: windows, interface, air

Is there any way to interface applications outside AIR application ? 
some kind of generic interface from AIR and into AIR ?

Answer (score 0):

in case required application is launched from inside AIR, then you can use Native Process API and all interactions with the applicaiton will be done using standard process streams (in, out, err).

whereas if application launched separately then i think one mode of interaction could be sockets.